# How can I set a for loop with settimeout that iterates backwards?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I may be approaching this in completely the wrong way, as I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to javascript, but essentially what I'm trying to do (for a bit of fun) is to have a cell of a table change colour onclick, then have the cells to the north, east, south, and west change to a different colour in sequence (think of the bomb effect in bomberman).

So far, I've managed to get the south direction to work using the following code:

```
function timeOutDown(i) {
  let bubbleRowPositive = col + rowArray[i];
  let bubbleRowPositiveId = document.getElementById(bubbleRowPositive);

  setTimeout(function() {
    bubbleRowPositiveId.style.backgroundColor = "#AA3333";
  },i * 50);
}

for (let i=row; i<colArray.length; i++) {
  timeOutDown(i);
}
```

*For context, there are 15 rows and 15 columns of evenly sized table cells, with ID's like "a1" and "h14".*

However, the issue I'm coming across is that the inverse will still iterate **upwards**, even when reversing the for loop and I can't figure out why:

```
function timeOutUp(k) {
  let bubbleRowNegative = col + rowArray[k];
  let bubbleRowNegativeId = document.getElementById(bubbleRowNegative);

  setTimeout(function() {
    bubbleRowNegativeId.style.backgroundColor = "#AA3333";
    console.log(`Index: ${k}, Row Num: ${rowArray[k]}`);
  },k * 50);
}

for (let k=row-2; k>=0; k--) {
  timeOutUp(k);
  console.log(k);
}
```

I had started by using the same function to handle both for loops, that didn't work, so I attempted this method using 2 separate functions.

Is there an easier way to go about this?

Comment: Because your delay doesn't change? It's still applies `k*50` for every iteration of your timeout there, so the first one is delayed by 0, the second by 50 etc... And that doesn't change if you reverse your loop since you pass in the index. You might want to add another counter variable and pass that in that counts up just as before.

Comment: The delay is what creates the "bubble" effect, so the cell you click changes to, say, red - then the surrounding cells are supposed to turn a different colour moving away from the clicked cell. What I'm finding is that the "bubble" effect moves away from the the clicked cell going downwards, but moves towards the clicked cell on those above. The delay is the only thing that makes the ripple effect.

Comment: I am not saying remove your delay, I am saying that your reversed loop makes no difference to the computed delay because they are index based, not order based. In short `k * 50 === i * 50`, there's nothing changing to that.

Comment: Ahh, I see, sorry. I'll have to take a different approach altogether it seems

Comment: Just store the actual call order (I put it in my answer). Basically keep another variable around the keeps track of the order (`i`) and one of the index (`k`). `i` counts up, `k` counts down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your for loop reversed, it still passes in the same index for every iteration, and that index is used to compute the delay it gets. So no matter what, the item at index `0` gets `0*50` milliseconds delay, regardless whether it happens first or last. You still need your original counter in order to define their ordered index. You could solve it like this:

```
function timeOutUp(k, i) {
  let bubbleRowNegative = col + rowArray[k];
  let bubbleRowNegativeId = document.getElementById(bubbleRowNegative);

  setTimeout(function() {
    bubbleRowNegativeId.style.backgroundColor = "#AA3333";
    console.log(`Index: ${k}, Row Num: ${rowArray[k]}`);
  },i * 50);
}

for (let k=row-2, i = 0; k>=0; k--, i++ ) {
  timeOutUp(k, i);
  console.log(k, i);
}
```

I just added 1 variable: `i` back in, that counts up. It gets passed to `timeOutUp` to compute the actual delay in the order you intend.

Comment: Ah fantastic, that certainly gets the upwards motion working, thank you!